# Uncaught ReferenceError: Spree is not defined

Tags: spree

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mounted_at')
at window.Spree.Spree.mountedAt (spree.self-77584b42ec80fc02086ac4b655219d17518c002660a93e6d91bd743a8e57949a.js?body=1:13:32)
at window.Spree.Spree.pathFor (spree.self-77584b42ec80fc02086ac4b655219d17518c002660a93e6d91bd743a8e57949a.js?body=1:23:51)
at spree.self-77584b42ec80fc02086ac4b655219d17518c002660a93e6d91bd743a8e57949a.js?body=1:54:28
at spree.self-77584b42ec80fc02086ac4b655219d17518c002660a93e6d91bd743a8e57949a.js?body=1:64:5
at spree.self-77584b42ec80fc02086ac4b655219d17518c002660a93e6d91bd743a8e57949a.js?body=1:66:4

I am on rails 5.1.7 and on Spree 3.4.0

Spree Object is not available in js, So nothing in working as far as datepickers and other things are concerned.

I tried adding spree.js in application.js file but not worked for me

Spree js file is visible in page source and it seems fine.